# How can I add a directive to all instances of Angular Material datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I have created a custom directive for checking manual entries in angular material date picker ([with help of here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16755#issuecomment-375330165)), and it is working.

**Q:** Is there any way to add that directive to all instances that are already present in the project without adding the directive one by one?

My directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as textMask from '../../../util/vanillaTextMask.js';

@Directive({
  selector: `fed-mask, [fed-mask], [fedMask]`
})
export class FedMaskDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @HostBinding('class.fed-mask') compClass = true;


  fedMask = {
    mask: [
      new RegExp('\\d'),
      new RegExp('\\d'),
      '.',
      new RegExp('\\d'),
      new RegExp('\\d'),
      '.',
      new RegExp('\\d'),
      new RegExp('\\d'),
      new RegExp('\\d'),
      new RegExp('\\d')
    ],
    showMask: false,
    guide: false,
    placeholderChar: '_'
  };

  maskedInputController;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.maskedInputController = textMask.maskInput({
      inputElement: this.element.nativeElement,
      ...this.fedMask
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.maskedInputController.destroy();
  }
}
```

how I'm currently using it:

```
  <mat-form-field>
                <input
                  (dateChange)="DateChange($event)"
                  formControlName="Date"
                  [matDatepicker]="Datepicker"
                  matInput
                  placeholder="Date"
                  (click)="Datepicker.open()"
                  fedMask
                >
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="Datepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #Datepicker></mat-datepicker>
                <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('Date').hasError('required')">
                  Error
                </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
```

**Expectation:**

is there any way to add the `fedMask` directive to every instance of material date picker input without manually adding it for every time it has been used in the whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any existing attribute as a selector, for example

```
@Directive({
  selector: "matDatepicker",
})
```

will target every element that has the attribute `matDatepicker` present on it.

Another example:

```
@Directive({selector: 'input:([matDatepicker])' })
```

will target every `input` with the `matDatepicker` attribute.

The same goes for tags:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "mat-datepicker",
})
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, I actually used :
```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input:([matDatepicker])'
})
```
and it worked completely, if it's ok, can you edit your answer so I can select it as the accepted answer @Mike-s?

Comment: @MasoudTahmasebi I've added your example. If your intention is to only add it to `input`s with said attribute, then that's the way to go